# Use of IdentityBasicAuthenticationAttribute in MVC 4 API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, token

How can I add the `IdentityBasicAuthenticationAttribute` in my project? I have read the link below shared by the @IonutUngureanu, but some of the steps are skipped in the document.

Please check the attached screenshot for the error.
[image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You could use or create a custom Authentication/Authorize filter attribute:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

Comment: I don't want any custom Authentication if I can get the Authorization value in Global.asax file?

Comment: Was that a question or an affirmation?... however.. you could try to use the Application_BeginRequest, but is not the standard approach

Comment: I am little bit confused in the link you have shared, I need to read it carefully. Thank You.

Comment: " if I can get the Authorization value in Global.asax " You don't want to start writhing you own custom auth since IIS is doing that. You just add GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new System.Web.MVC.AuthorizeAttribute()); And all controllers will be protected(for web api use System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute). The link is MVC core dow.

Comment: @FilipCordas do I get any specific link that will explain in Step by Step in a simple manner.

Comment: @Chandresh Khambhayata Here is an old one for MVC4. But some of it might be a bit out of date, it depends on the exact version of MVC.  https://www.codeproject.com/articles/654846/security-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2):

From your picture I see that you are missing the implementation of the IdentityBasicAuthenticationAttribute class. Step by step instructions:

1. Create a folder called Filters
2. In the folder Filters create a class called IdentityBasicAuthenticationAttribute  :

   ```
   public class IdentityBasicAuthenticationAttribute : BasicAuthenticationAttribute
   {
       protected override async Task<IPrincipal> AuthenticateAsync(string userName, string password, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {
           // Implement logic suitable for your case           
           return new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Register your filter:
      `config.Filters.Add(new IdentityBasicAuthenticationAttribute());`

Full code sample here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/BasicAuthentication/BasicAuthentication/Filters/IdentityBasicAuthenticationAttribute.cs

Comment: Thanks again. I will give it a try now.

Comment: Sorry but I am totally new in this and I am unable to find the `BasicAuthenticationAttribute` now

Comment: You are probably missing a reference or a nuget package. In the full code you can see in the file packages.config the used and in the code file you can see the using references.

Comment: Okay, I will check the package.config and add each package 1 by 1.